# Why does LIBVA return an error while trying to init Intel GM965 driver?

Tags: intel-graphics, vaapi

Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, Intel 965GM chipset.

Here is the result of `vainfo` command:

```
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit.
```

This file is actually exists, `libva-intel-vaapi-driver` is installed, even path to `libva_driver` is written to `/etc/environment`. I've tried to install those drivers with or without stopping the `lightdm` service, with bleeding edge Intel drivers or with standard canonical drivers, already. But have all the same result as at the beginning of the post.

update: after [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAAPI) [research](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/community/vaapi) i have found that there is a non-zero possibility that VAAPI doesn't support GM965 (X3100) chipset. Is it really so?

Comment: The error does not say that `i965_drv_video.so` doesn't exist, it says that the initialization failed. This can happen for a number of reasons, first of all using restricted drivers. Are you using `fglrx`?

Comment: @Andrea, "unfortunately" no, i don't use such driver, even more - i've just found and fully destroyed xserver-xorg-video-radeon pack. But nothing has changed after reboot. But i like the way you think - maybe there are another conflicting packs/drivers installed "by default".

Comment: Doing some research, it looks like that the GM960 and GM965 chipsets are supported **only via the [IEGD](http://edc.intel.com/Software/Downloads/IEGD/) driver**. Probably someone with more knowledge on the topic can provide some input.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, could you please provide me some more information about it? Cause from this [link](http://edc.intel.com/Download.aspx?id=1903) i knew that the latest available version of such driver doesn't support any hardware video acceleration and kernel version newer than 2.6.xx.

Comment: Sorry, I can't :-( My knowledge on the topic is very limited and I do not have similar chipsets to test, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should say that answer as simple as sad: from [this 01.org link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/community/vaapi) and [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAAPI) I knew that my GM965 chipset in particular isn't supported by VA-API.

Answer (score -1):

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/2013q1-intel-graphics-stack-release

Apparently it is supported now but I guess we will need to either find a PPA or wait for them to hit the repos as it would be too much effort to get going and certainly keep going really.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: No it isn't. VAAPI is only supported from GM45/X4500HD and up. https://01.org/linuxgraphics/community/vaapi