# 19.10 video players crash when trying to seek Flash video file

Tags: video, 19.10, vlc

I'm trying to play a video via CLI in Ubuntu 19.10

I run the command:

```
con@e:/mnt/Windows/Users/...$ vlc video.flv
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[000056347c5755b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f7e20003430] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f7e20003430] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f7e20003430] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[flv @ 0x7f7e34c160c0] Unable to seek to the next packet
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

The video plays in both Totem and VLC, but when I try to seek to another time, the whole thing crashes.  Totem does not print an error report, but VLC does so I pasted it above.

I have seen similar posts here, such as https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387235
but I don't see a solution there or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-vaapi-driver/+bug/1756380

I've also seen [Why does LIBVA return an error while trying to init Intel GM965 driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248732/why-does-libva-return-an-error-while-trying-to-init-intel-gm965-driver) but I don't understand anything there that can help me.

listing the `libva2` package, I see:

```
libva2/eoan,now 2.5.0-1 amd64 [installed]
libva2/eoan 2.5.0-1 i386
```

This error only happens for *some* videos, not others, and I don't know which ones exactly.

I've also seen [VLC crashed when trying to play video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117542/vlc-crashed-when-trying-to-play-video)

which suggests I do:

```
con@e:/mnt/Windows/Users/...$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

unfortunately that page is still unsolved after > 1 year.

I have also looked at https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=148280
but the solution there: `vlc -V x11 video.mp4` still returns the same error.

VLC has the same problem when opening the same file from windows.

output from `mediainfo`:

```
con@e:/mnt/Windows/Users/...$ file.flv 
General
Complete name                            : file.flv
Format                                   : Flash Video
File size                                : 167 MiB
Tagged date                              : UTC 2009-05-30 03:59:09
Tagging application                      : MEGA

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 5 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : 7
Width                                    : 416 pixels
Height                                   : 224 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive

Audio
```

Comment: 1) If a Flash video file fails, what happens w/ AVI & MPEG files? 2) Please copy the Flash video file to your /home directory & run it there. 3) What happens when you launch playback of the file in the File Manager instead of from the Command Line?  4) If mediainfo http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/mediainfo.1.html is not installed, please install it with _sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y mediainfo mediainfo-gui_ , run mediainfo on each failing file & share each file's profile w/ us.by clickin [edit] and putting the profile data into your question for each failing test file.

Comment: Question is, what kind of film you're trying to watch. Seems to me, that its encoding is either broken or not seekable. VLC is an extreme robust videoplayer, if it can't seek (e.g. HVEC or AV1 codecs) either the codec doesn't provide it or the encoding is faulty... It would be very interesting to see the ouput of mediainfo...

Comment: Might be worth re-encoding the file, is it available online somewhere?

Comment: @K7AAY I've edited to include the output from mediainfo.  I get the same error when I open from the file browser and when I copy the file to the home directory

Comment: @kanehekili I've edited to include the output from mediainfo

Comment: @andrew.46 the video is 11 years old, I don't remember where I got it :( how could I re-encode it?

Comment: @con You have cut the audio from your mediainfo output but looks like H.264 video so probably AAC sound. You could try copying to a different container for starters: `ffmpeg -i file.flv -c copy test.mp4` This will copy first video and first audio streams (plus subtitles if they are present). If no improvement next is re-encode which will give a small loss in quality...

Comment: @andrew.46 the audio wasn't cut, that's exactly what mediainfo showed :( nonetheless, your `ffmpeg` seems to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file is probably damaged, as seems to be the case with your file, there are a couple of good choices:

1. **Simply change the container**. In your case you have AVC or H.264 in an flv container and either no sound or more than likely AAC sound. Both of these codecs live quite happily in an mp4 container. So the following would be best to *remux* your file:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i file.flv -c copy test.mp4
   ```

   This would not be helpful if either video or audio codec were themselves damaged. Important to note as well that `-c:copy` only copies the *first* of all streams...
2. **Re-encode the file + new container.** If remuxing is unsuccessful *re-encoding* would be another option with the caveat that there would be an appreciable loss of quality. Something like the following would accomplish this by re-encoding *the video stream*:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i file.flv -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy test.mp4
   ```

   If the audio stream (if this exists) is damaged you could also re-encode this by using `-c:a aac -b:a 128k`.

And hopefully this will resurrect your old file :)